# iOS extension and restricted API

Tags: ios, api, private

I share a framework between an app and it's action extension. The framework uses API that is not available to extensions.

My question is: Is the app going to get rejected if I keep there references to APIs such as `UIApplication.sharedApplication` without actually calling them (setting “Require Only App-Extension-Safe API” to NO), or do I need to completely remove any references from the code (i.e. using `#ifdef`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it will be rejected even if it references restricted APIs. We are going through the same process to remove such calls in our framework, alternatively you can have two targets for your framework, one extension-safe and one not with #ifdef guards.

Apple docs: (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html)

> If you have a custom framework that does contain such APIs, you can
>   safely link to it from your containing app but cannot share that code
>   with the app’s contained extensions. The App Store **rejects any app
>   extension that links to such frameworks** or that otherwise uses
>   unavailable APIs."

Answer (score -3):

**Update for iOS 9**: Apple is removing access to invalid frameworks for specific targets, so you won't be able to reference unavailable APIs regardless, and will have to follow what the accepted answer states.

-- Original Answer --

If it's not a huge inconvenience, it's probably best to `#ifdef` around the references. It will make your code more forward-compatible in the event Apple ever decides in the future to break compilation if your extension references the restricted API (much like they did with trying to get the UUID of the device).

In addition, this will make your framework usable in other scenarios where you might not have UIKit access, like on OS X.

Comment: Thanks but that does not really answer my question.